# ASRock Rack X570D4U IPMI login failed after password change

Tags: ipmi, bmc

I upgraded my servers mainboard to a ASRock Rack X570D4U.
When i opened the IPMI web interface I logged in with admin/admin.

The web interface asked me to change my password. I generated a 24 char long password with letters, numbers and special characters and saved it to my password manager.
After I changed the password, the web interface instructed me to login again with the new password.
But now I can't login with the password. The error message is: `Login Failed`

Is it possible to reset the password without access to a monitor? I can't find a VGA cable and the HDMI port doesn't work, because the CPU has no iGPU.
There is a "I forgot my password" button, but it says: `Unable to reset the Password for the User. Please try again later`

Comment: try to `Load BMC Default Settings` in `Server Mgmt` > `BMC Tools` BIOS menu.

Comment: that worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

The maximum length for your password is 16 characters. Try the first 16 to get in. Worked for me.

Otherwise you can try to make a bootable DOS USB and add a tool onto it called IPMICFG (Read the documentation on how to use it) to reset the password.